# Error adjuntar FullCalendar en proyecto Laravel

Tags: jquery, npm, laravel-6, fullcalendar

Estoy intentando adjuntar FullCalendar en mi proyecto de Laravel 6. He instalado los paquetes según la web de [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) (ES6 Build System) y todo funciona mientras ponga todo el código en `.\resources\js\app.js`. Adjunto código:
**app.js**

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

El problema lo tengo cuando quiero trasladar esto a la vista. Lo quito de **app.js** y lo pongo en los siguientes archivos:

**app.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    
    <link href='node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    @yield('scripts')

  .
  .
  .

</html>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
        .
        .
        .
@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script>
    import { Calendar } from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/core';
    import dayGridPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid';
    import timeGridPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid';
    import listPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/list';
    import interactionPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/interaction';

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        .
        .
        .
    });

</script>
@endsection
```

El error que me da en consola es:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que es porque la `@section('scripts')` va antes de la `@section('content')` y no al final: deberia quedar algo asi:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('scripts')
<script>
    import { Calendar } from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/core';
    import dayGridPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid';
    import timeGridPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid';
    import listPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/list';
    import interactionPlugin from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/interaction';

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        .
        .
        .
    });

</script>
@endsection
@section('content')
        .
        .
        .
@endsection
```

Revisa tambien como cargas los scripts del fullcalendar, quizas debes intentar con:
`<script src="{{ asset('direccion_donde_esta_el_js_de_fc') }}" defer></script>`
ya que el `asset` referencia a lo que tienes en la carpeta public, esto lo puedes hacer desde el `index.blade.php` o tambien el `app.blade.php`, avisame si te sirve o si ya habias resuelto, comparte tu solucion

Answer (score 0):

No ps, como vas a pones `ES6` en una `vista`

```
import { Calendar } from 'node_modules/@fullcalendar/core';
```

esto hay que compilar primero, si estas usando `vue`, `react` u `otro`, basta con agregar el `archivo.js` compilado resultante,

en caso de no usar una `biblioteca front-end` basta solo con agregar los `CDN`

**app.blade.php**

```
...
@stack('css')
@stack('js')
...
```

**index.blade.php**

```
...
@push('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css" />
@endpush
@push('js')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
@endpush
...
```